# TYPO3 Problem - Page has wrong user Group (7.6.24)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I run a TYPO3 mulitroot installation with about 20 domains.
We have a problem, that always a user creates a new page, it has the wrong group and I have to change the group in "Access".

```
User1 has Group1
User2 has Group1
User1 creates a new page (Page1). 
this page grants Access for User1 and Group2 ( User1 does not have permission for Group2!!)

User2 does not have Access for Page1
User1, and User2  are no admins
why has Page1 the default Group2??
```

can you help?

Comment: Off topic: Please update to 7.6.30. There is a security issue in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can set ownership in TSconfig for pages:

```
[PIDinRootline = 20]
    TCEMAIN.permissions {
        userid = 12
        groupid = 23
    }
[GLOBAL]
```

Explanation: All subpages of page id=20 get ownership of user id=12 and group id=23.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some broken page / user tsconfig settings, you should check especially for TCEMAIN.permissions, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TceMain.html#permissions for more details.